# How do I simplify the below statements with a loop in SAS?

Tags: sas

I need to repeat the below proc sort from int1 to int10. What is an efficient way to code this?

```
Proc sort data=sourceh.average_metric_Jan2009_int1;
by time rank;
run;

Proc sort data=sourceh.average_metric_Jan2009_int2;
by time rank;
run;
```

Comment: use macro variable in a loop. 
%do% i = 1 %to% 10; 
Proc sort data=sourceh.average_metric_Jan2009_int&i.;
by time rank;
run;
end;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `%do` loop inside a macro program:

```
%macro multisort();

%do i = 1 %to 10;
  proc sort data = sourceh.average_metric_jan2009_int&i;
  by time rank;
  run;
%end;

%mend;


%multisort()
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're doing after you've sorted all the datasets, it might be easier to concatenate them all together, and then sort them.

```
data int1_to_10 ;
  set sourceh.average_metric_Jan2009_int1-sourceh.average_metric_Jan2009_int10 ;
run ;
proc sort data=int1_to_10 ;
  by time rank ;
run ;
```